# Index and Match across a wide range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of data in a few columns, but basically:

Bunch #1 (column A,B):

```
CHR     POS
1     126234
3     5555555
3     9999999
9     3700000
```

Bunch #2 (column E,F,G):

```
CHR     POS     INDEX
1     1129410     1
2     4500000     2
3     5555155     3
3     9997999     4
7     3700000     5
```

I wish to add a column in Bunch #1 such that if the CHR column of both bunches are the same, AND the POS column of #2 is within +/-500 of POS in #1, then copy over the index of Bunch #2.

Like so (Column A,B,C):

```
CHR     POS     NEW_COLUMN
1     126234     #N/A
3     5555555     3
3     9999999     #N/A
9     3700000     #N/A
```

I got as far as getting exact matches for both columns in C

```
{=INDEX(E:G,match(1,(E:E=A1)*(F:F=B1),0),3)}`
```

Some help in getting the range condition into the match would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean **±5000** so that 9997999 would match?

Comment: @Jeeped No, I wanted my example to show cases that wouldn't match despite having the same CHR (double check against coding error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) makes quick work of multiple conditions. In C2 as,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G$1:G$9, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9)/((E$1:E$9=A2)*(F$1:F$9<=B2+500)*(F$1:F$9>=B2-500)), 1)), "no match")
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: aggregate_multi_plus_minus]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Amazing. I worked out a tedious answer which is giving me problems. Essentially returning the rows of which E=AK2 using `if (A2=E:E,row(E:E)-min(row(E:E))+1,"")`, then getting the POS values corresponding to AK2 using `index(E:E, <previous chunk>`; then returning rows which F:F is within 500 of B2 using `if(abs(B2-<previous chunk>) > 500, row(G:G)-min(row(G:G)+1,"")`; `small` that chunk; then index G again for the answer. Obviously, I got bogged down by errors here and there :(

Comment: The AGGREGATE function works well for this. By ignoring errors, all you have to do is create a simple division formula where the non-matches have a denominator equates to zero (`#DIV/0!` error). Additionally, sub-function **15** is actually a SMALL so it is easy to get the second, third, etc match by raising the *k* parameter.